# Can not access folder with permission

Tags: linux, file-permissions

eI am having some trouble with permissions in /etc

```
drw-rw-re- MyUser:tomcat7 /etc/tomcat7
```

When I try to access `/etc/tomcat7` with as MyUser, I get Permission denied.

In folder `/etc/tomcat7` the permissions are set as follows:

```
drw-rw-rw- MyUser:tomcat7 .
drwxr-xr-x root:root ..
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go into a directory on Linux/Unix, you need to set the execute bit for that folder.

A common set of permissions on a directory would be:

```
chmod 755 /etc/tomcat7
```

And would allow read-write access to MyUser and read-only access to all other users.